# math.sum how to pass a collection of values as argument?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, math, math.js

i started to use math.js just for convenience and i was wondering if i could use math.sum method and pass
a collection of input values as argument and return the sum of all input values,for example,something like this :

code to visualize my concept :

```js
$(document).ready ( function(){
   $("#sum").val(math.sum($("#container input")))
});
```

```css
input{
position:relative;
float:left;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
}
#sum{
margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"><input value="15"><input value="5"><input value="10"><input value="20"></div>
<input id="sum" placeholder="SUM OF ABOVE INPUTS">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math.sum method expects a **JS Array** so you need to build it from what you have to comply with the requirement.

In just one line you can go from Jquery Objects to your expected Array.

[Jquery DOM Elements].get() **=>** [ES6 DOM Elements].map() **=>** JS Arrays

```js
$("#sum").val(math.sum($("#container input").get().map(v=>v.value)))
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

#sum {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"><input value="15"><input value="5"><input value="10"><input value="20"></div>
  <input id="sum" placeholder="SUM OF ABOVE INPUTS">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the element values to an array first.

The math library doesn't know anything about getting values from a jQuery collection of elements

Simple case with no validation:

```js
const values = $("#container input").toArray().map(el => el.value)
$("#sum").val(math.sum(values))
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

#sum {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"><input value="15"><input value="5"><input value="10"><input value="20"></div>
  <input id="sum" placeholder="SUM OF ABOVE INPUTS">
</body>

</html>
```